# Selecting rows in jQuery

Tags: jquery, row, selection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery: How to select rows from a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585272/jquery-how-to-select-rows-from-a-table)

I am a beginner in jQuery. I have a table with multiple rows, how do I select next row or previous row after selecting a particular row?

Answer (score 1):

For the next row (assuming myRow is your selected row element):

```
$(myRow).next();
```

I'd recommend using the very powerful selector syntax, instead of selecting previous and next elements based on currently selected element instances, however:

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).next();
```

or

```
$(this).prev();
```

Comment: I am selecting a row using "onclick" event and changing its class name to "xyz". now I want the next row to the row with classname "xyz".

I have used $(".xyz").next() & $(".xyz").prev(), but the result set is empty.