# JQuery: How to select rows from a table

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a scenario where I would like to select rows from a table depending upon the values in td

e.g. I have a table like this

```
<tr>
   <td>John</td>
   <td>Smith</td>
   <td>Male</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Andy</td>
   <td>Gates</td>
   <td>Male</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Alice</td>
   <td>Nixon</td>
   <td>Female</td>
</tr>
```

now I would like to select all the rows if the value of first td is x **AND**  value of second td is y

At the momemnt I am doing something like this

```
$("tr").each(function (index) {
   if ($(this).find('td:eq(0)').text().trim() == x &&
       $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text().trim() == y)
          ...do somethin....
});
```

looping through each row and check. This is verbose. Is there a better way to achieve this in a single line. I can't seem to figure out AND operator logic with selectors?

Awaiting,

Comment: Off-topic: Just a reminder that `.trim()` will fail in some browsers.

Comment: whats is the alternative then ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("tr").each(function (index) {
   if ($.trim($(this).find('td:eq(0)').text()) == x &&
       $.trim($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text()) == y) {
       $(this).closest('table').css('border', '1px solid red');​ // this should do it
   }
});
```

Alternatively, using [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$("tr").filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).find('td:eq(0)').text()) == 'John' &&
           $.trim($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text()) == 'Smith';
}).closest('table').find('tr').css('border', '1px solid red');​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WhFbE/5/

Answer (score 3):

Here's a selector that should work:

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/N6TdM/

```
var x = "Andy";
var y = "Gates";

var res = $("td:first-child:contains(" + x + ") + td:contains(" + y + ")");
```

Note that this *could* fail if you have something like the following:

```
FIRST:   Roberto       Rob
SECOND:  Robertson     Roberts
```

Searching for "Rob Roberts" would give two matches.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [native DOM `cells` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#ID-67349879) on the HTMLTableRowElement to access the cells directly, rather than sending jQuery on a roundabout trip with listing all descendant cells and picking out one with the non-standard `:eq` selector.

```
$('tr').each(function (index) {
    if (
        $(this.cells[0]).text().trim()===x &&
        $(this.cells[1]).text().trim()===y
    ) {
        ...
    }
});
```

though it probably won't make a serious performance difference. Another approach would be simply to maintain an array-of-arrays containing the pre-trimmed data to save even looking at the DOM.