# How do I select specific rows from HTML table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery: How to select rows from a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585272/jquery-how-to-select-rows-from-a-table)

I want to select specific rows of a table based on certain conditions using jquery.  For example, If a table has 25 rows with a checkbox column to check each row, I want to specify a condition and if that condition is true, then only the checkbox should be checked, for example, 5 rows satisfy that condition, so only 5 rows should be checked.  This selection may be dependent on other columns of the table. How do I achieve this with jquery?

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this,

```
var chkbox = $('#yourTableId tr').eq(indexOfRowYouWant).find(':checkbox').attr('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( 'tr', table ).each(function () {

    this // refers to the current TR element

    // check if the condition is met for this row
    var conditionMet = ...

    // and set the checked state accordingly 
    $( '.checkbox', this )[0].checked = conditionMet;

});
```

where `table` is a reference to your TABLE element, and `"checkbox"` is the class of the `<input type=checkbox>` element within each row.